# Java DTO class design for partial persistance and serialization?

Tags: java, hibernate, jackson

I have a complex Java DTO (Data Transfer Object pattern) class with hundreds of properties. For illustration purposes consider just two

```
class PointlessExample {
    private int x;
    private int y;
    public ... // getters/setters
}
```

What is the best way to refactor this into two classes so that some subset of attributes ('x') can be persisted separately from the full class, and serialized either separately or together with the full class?

My simple idea was:

```
@Entity 
class PointlessBase {
    private int x;
    ...
}
class PointlessExample extends PointlessBase {
    private int y;
    ...
}
```

The problem however, is that objects can start their lifecyle as the full class (`PointlessExample`), and although they would always be persisted as `PointlessBase`, I have use-cases to serialize and deserialize as either the full or the partial object (including, deserialize a partial object from a full serialized object). There is no easy way to serialize (through Jackson) or persist (through Hibernate) only the `PointlessBase` fields belonging to a `PointlessExample` object. Or is there?

Comment: maybe `@Transient` and `@JsonIgnore` would do the job >? Otherwise gonna need DTOs(not persistent entities) or custom property wrappers

Comment: @AntJavaDev that won't work, as soon as I start adding JsonIgnore, I lose the ability to serialize the entire class. Also, this is a DTO that I'm trying to design, so that 2nd part is a circular recommendation :-)

Comment: well yea , didnt see the later edit , but still , you are not creating a divided DTO or a helper/builder that would create it , but you are creating an entity(TABLE) and you want to reuse it as a JSON.....so either create a proper entity that would be fed from the DTO/JSON Wrapper , or the Opposite. The trap there is that you need to maintain two objects(refactor) and separate the fields

Comment: Also, I wanted to avoid having to add @Transient to every single member of the derived class (in the refactored example)>

Comment: @AntJavaDev I don't mind separating the fields based on their intended persistability/serializability, but one thing I really wouldn't want, is having to repeat some large set of field definitions on two separate classes.

Comment: whats the problem then, inheriting only whats common <<??? Or maintain a common base instance instead of extending it? Or i dont get your use case?

Comment: Yes, inheriting the common fields is the impetus behind my simple idea. But the simple idea doesn't work, it runs into many issues. For instance, the subclass is not an @Entity, so Hibernate doesn't like it, even though it should be able to stand-in for one.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I'm not quite sure what you meant by "maintain a common base instance instead of extending it", can you explain?

Comment: woops soz , it was indeed unclear , well simple instead of `B extends A` try `B has A` , so you will hold a state for B instead of inheriting

Comment: The problem with `B has A` is the huge breakage due to removing dozens of members from `B` (remember this is a Refactoring, not fresh code). I could mitigate that by adding delegating getters/setters from B to A, but even that still seems like a lot of repetition and potential maintenance headache.

Comment: yeap , in case of thousands fields , as you'r saying , cant see any valid solution that will potential avoid maintenance headaches......Maybe from start , its a wrong overall design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTO is generally a [painful concept](http://www.yegor256.com/2016/07/06/data-transfer-object.html).
Your idea of separating properties using inheritance sounds fine.
If I understand your requirements, you need something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
| Class            | JSON | Hibernate |
---------------------------------------
| PointlessBase    | YES  | YES       |
---------------------------------------
| PointlessExample | YES  | NO        |
---------------------------------------
```

In `Jackson` you can customise process of serialization of deserialization and generally ignore properties which comes from given type or by other filters. For example see my simple class filter:

```
class ClassIgnoranceIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector {

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    ClassIgnoranceIntrospector(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    public boolean hasIgnoreMarker(AnnotatedMember m) {
        return m.getDeclaringClass() != clazz;
    }
}
```

Below you can find how to use it:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMember;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ObjectMapper baseMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        baseMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        baseMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new ClassIgnoranceIntrospector(PointlessBase.class));

        ObjectMapper extendedMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        extendedMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
        extendedMapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new ClassIgnoranceIntrospector(PointlessExample.class));

        List<PointlessBase> list = Arrays.asList(new PointlessBase(), new PointlessExample());
        for (PointlessBase item : list) {
            System.out.println("Base only mapper for class " + item.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + baseMapper.writeValueAsString(item));
            System.out.println("Extended only mapper for class " + item.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + extendedMapper.writeValueAsString(item));
        }
    }
}
```

Above prints:

```
Base only mapper for class PointlessBase {"x":10}
Extended only mapper for class PointlessBase {}
Base only mapper for class PointlessExample {"x":10}
Extended only mapper for class PointlessExample {"y":11}
```

You can use different instance of `ObjectMapper` to serialize specific set of properties. If you wont to serialize/deserialize all properties use default `ObjectMapper`.

Another idea is using [Jackson JSON Views](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-json-view-annotation). For more information how to handle properly inheritance with `Jackson` read [Inheritance with Jackson](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-inheritance).

Comment: This `ClassIgnoranceIntrospector` seems like a great idea, let me give it a try.